# Adding buttons with different width and horizontal separator in CKEditor

Tags: javascript, css, ckeditor

Is it possible to add several wider buttons to the CKEditor toolbar?

I know how to make all of them wider by changing width parameter in *editor.css*:

[image: CSS]

but I only need several buttons, in similar to "source button" style:

[image: Source]

Any hints?

### UPDATE

Ok, lets say I want to widen icon of this plugin:

```
CKEDITOR.plugins.add( 'timestamp',
    {
        init: function( editor )
        {
            editor.addCommand( 'insertTimestamp',
                {
                    exec : function( editor )
                    {    
                        var timestamp = new Date();
                        editor.insertHtml( 'The current date and time is: <em>' + timestamp.toString() + '</em>' );
                    }
                });
            editor.ui.addButton( 'Timestamp',
            {
                label: 'Insert Timestamp',
                command: 'insertTimestamp',
                icon: this.path + 'images/timestamp.png'
            } );
        }
    } );
```

and former result I got by adding this:

```
.cke_button_insertTimestamp { width: 32px !important; }
```

this doesn't change anything:

```
#cke_11 {
    width: 32px ;
}
```

no matter what integer I choose, and I don't see any integers like you mentioned while inspecting. I have CKEditor  build in IPBoard maybe that's the issue?

What should I add? Sorry for me being noob

### UPDATE

Ok I got this at last and have identical results - half icon. Is it about this .cke_icon class which defines 16px width? Many icons share this class. Don't know how to get around or delete it

### UPDATE

```
#cke_61 .cke_icon { width:32px; }
```

This code did the job thanks a million!

Final question, how do I add horizontal separator below my new icon row like other rows have:

[image]

Vertical one I've added in *ips_config.js* using this:

```
['Timestamp'],['-'],
```

but horizontal I have no idea

Comment: Use the developer tools to inspect the html structure of CKeditor and see what classes and ids are applied to your button. I guess you are close with `.cke_button_insertTimestamp`. I think you need the child element.

Comment: Don't place code as pictures. Add it to your question. You can select this `cke_icon` with `#cke_61 .cke_icon { width:32px; }`. This is basic CSS. Search and read about 'css selectors'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every button has an unique id. A line of CSS is all that is needed to adjust the width of a button:

```
#cke_11 { width: 120px; }
```

[image: Cut at 120px;]

`#cke_11` is the first button (cut) on the [demo page](http://ckeditor.com/demo#standard).

All buttons contain a label. This label is a string of text and hidden with `.cke_button_label { display: none; }`. If you remove this line of CSS or set the value to `inline`. You'll get this:

[image: All buttons with label]

That is the reason the Source button is wider. Source button has a class `cke_button__source_label`. This class sets `display` to `inline`.

If you only want to show a single label:

```
#cke_11_label { display: inline; }
```

[image: Cut button with label]

Use your Developer Tools that come with your browser to inspect elements and fiddle with the css.

Comment: Thank you very much. I wanted to change from 16px to 32px width and I added this:


    .cke_button_mybutton {
        width: 32px !important;
    }

It finally worked but only altered the background of the button. My icon is cut off and shown as if it was still 16px. How do I go about that?

Comment: You are selecting the wrong element. I guess you select the parent element. To be sure you should provide a working example. The selector is wrong. Use `#cke_??` where ?? is a integer.